# Display elements of a list with there index in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I have a list of numbers :

```
   list = [0.5, 0.88, 1, 0.65 ]
```

I want to display elements of this list with there index, and the start index to be **2**

To get something like :

```
2 0.5
3 0.88
4 1
5 0.65
```

How can i add the index in the display ?

```
maplist(writeln, List).
```

Comment: See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numlist/3 and click on the orange circle to see the sourcecode. Then adapt to suit.

Comment: Also asked at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/print-element-of-lisrs-with-indexes/5656

Answer (score 0):

Basic Prolog recursive list walk, C being the number to start counting:

```
enum([],     [],       _).
enum([X|Xs], [C-X|Ys], C) :-
    succ(C,C2),
    enum(Xs, Ys, C2).


?- List = [0.5, 0.88, 1, 0.65 ],
   enum(List, Answer, 2).

Answer = [2-0.5, 3-0.88, 4-1, 5-0.65]
```

---

All the [nth1/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1%2f3) indices+1 paired with the elements:

```
?- List = [0.5, 0.88, 1, 0.65 ],
   findall(I-X, (nth1(I0, List, X),succ(I0,I)), Answer).

Answer = [2-0.5, 3-0.88, 4-1, 5-0.65]
```

---

DCG Remeniscent of Python's enumerate(), `I` being the index to start counting:

```
enum(_, [])       --> [].
enum(I, [I-E|Es]) --> [E], {succ(I,I2)}, enum(I2, Es).


?- List = [0.5, 0.88, 1, 0.65 ],
   phrase(enum(2,Answer), List).

Answer = [2-0.5, 3-0.88, 4-1, 5-0.65]
```

---

More remeniscent of Python's `zip`:

```
?-  List = [0.5, 0.88, 1, 0.65],
    length(List, LLen),
    End is LLen + 1,
    numlist(2, End, Indices),
    pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Indices, List).

Indices = [2, 3, 4, 5],
Pairs = [2-0.5, 3-0.88, 4-1, 5-0.65]
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! Iis there a way to print the Key value pairs in the format X Y with the dash '-' ?